# Deploying Asp.Net MVC 2 /C# 4.0 application on IIS 6

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2, iis-6

I got a problem migrating from **VS.Net 2008** / **MVC 1** to **VS.NET 2010** (+C# 4.0) / **MVC 2**

The [web.config has been updated](http://screencast.com/t/MDVmYzhhO), the site runs well in Cassini, but my problem now is deploying on IIS 6.

I updated the web site to run using [ASP.Net 4](http://screencast.com/t/ZDljOWVh),
but whatever URL I try, I always have a 404 error. It's as if the routing was not taken into account (yes, the [wildcard mapping](http://screencast.com/t/ZGZhNGViOTkt) has been done).

I do not understand this mess and could not google anything interesting...
Thanks for your suggestions !

Comment: I tried to deploy the default project created using 'add new project...' and encountered the same problems. Still googling for answers, but hoping for your advices....

Comment: I always got screwed with the wildcard mapping and that goddamn "verify file exists" checkbox.  Scrub everything, start from square one, and follow this: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/07/04/options-for-deploying-aspnet-mvc-to-iis-6/ and when I say scrub everything, I mean SCRUB EVERYTHING.  Don't assume something is correct.  Start at square one and triple check everything.

Comment: I did it again but it's still not working.
The application I'm working with is working perfectly in MVC 1, but since I passed to .Net 4 / MVC 2, routing is broken...
As  I said in my previous comment I tried with the sample app and cannot make it work.
Thanks for your help. Any other suggestion ?

Comment: I have the same problem,  I'm getting a 404 on everything and I started from square one

Comment: it is worth noting that with .NET 4, it is no longer necessary to have an isapi wildcard mapping to get extensionless urls to work in IIS6.

http://blogs.msdn.com/tmarq/archive/2010/04/01/asp-net-4-0-enables-routing-of-extensionless-urls-without-impacting-static-requests.aspx

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ok I got y answer (thanks to a colleague)

When migrating from ASP.Net 2.0 to ASP.Net4.0,
if you meet the same problem,
then check in ***Web Service Extension*** if ASP.Net v4 is **Allowed**.

In my case, after installing the .Net framework 4, it was prohibited.

Will & Mark : thanks for your help, hope it will helps others.

Answer (score 6):

I think I know what's happening: on IIS6, as well as the wildcard mapping you will need a default document (Default.aspx) that routes folder requests to the MVC handler.

There was one included with the MVC1 project templates, but [it has been removed](http://forums.asp.net/t/1504834.aspx) in MVC2.

`Default.aspx`:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="YourNameSpace._Default" %>

<%-- Please do not delete this file. It is used to ensure that ASP.NET MVC is activated by IIS when a user makes a "/" request to the server. --%>
```

and `Default.aspx.cs`:

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace YourNameSpace
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        public void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            // Change the current path so that the Routing handler can correctly interpret
            // the request, then restore the original path so that the OutputCache module
            // can correctly process the response (if caching is enabled).

            string originalPath = Request.Path;
            HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(Request.ApplicationPath, false);
            IHttpHandler httpHandler = new MvcHttpHandler();
            httpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext.Current);
            HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(originalPath, false);
        }
    }
}
```

When you say "It's as if the routing was not taken into account", I suspect that it actually isn't, and this is your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I already had a Default.aspx with almost the same code-behind.
I tried to use you code (the only difference was the ending Rewritepath back to the original path), but it's still not working.
Nonetheless, I got a BIG CLUE : when i try my root url (or any url for that application), IIS returns me the 404 error VERY QUICKLY, event after a iisreset or a server reboot. I suppose it does not load anything ! Checking for issues in that way with C# 4.0.
(FYI, the url is http://push.widgetbooster.com)

Comment: Wow I was going crazy with this issue (I use mvc 2 in .net 3.5 w/ IIS 6) but this solved it! thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This finally fixed it for me:

I commented earlier, and a wee bit prematurely.  My comment to Mark B's post was getting my initial Index view to show up, but then I kept getting the 404 errors whenever I navigated to any other view.

I was also distracted by the green check mark approved solution in this particular forum, but I could not even see the web server extensions folder in IIS 6 on my desktop; therefore, I had no control from that stand point of enabling aspnet 4.0, though I made sure it was installed by performing running the following command line:

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319> aspnet_regiis -i
```

Now for the actual piece that finally allowed me to navigate to the other views besides just my Home/Index:

In the `Global.asax.cs` file of your VS 2010 Solution, you will see code as follows in the `RegisterRoutes` method:

```
  routes.MapRoute(
      "Default", // Route name
      "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
      new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

I simply added ".aspx" after the {action} section of the tag as follows:

```
  routes.MapRoute(
      "Default", // Route name
      "{controller}/{action}.aspx/{id}", // URL with parameters
      new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

And ahla wahla Peanut Butter and Jelly sandwiches.  :0)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in C#, just add the System.DirectoryServices reference and this piece should do the job nicely.

```
DirectoryEntry w3svc = new DirectoryEntry("IIS://localhost/W3SVC");
w3svc.Invoke("EnableWebServiceExtension", "ASP.NET v4.0.30319");
w3svc.CommitChanges();
```

HTH