# ASP.NET 4.0 MVC2 routing on IIS 6

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, iis-6, asp.net-4.0

ASP.NET 4.0 MVC2 routing on IIS 6 is not working for me with all the methods used for 3.5
Works fine as long as I build in 3.5 but building in 4.0 and setting the server to use 4.0 I loose my routing. Anyone seen this and been able to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked to make sure that ASP.NET 4.0 is allowed in the web service extensions after upgrading to .NET 4.0 on the server?

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319498/deploying-asp-net-mvc-2-c-4-0-application-on-iis-6).