# Deploying MVC2 app iis6 on Window Server 2003 R2 x64

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, iis-6

I am having an issue deploying MVC2 app on Window Server 2003 R2 x64. Does anyone have the same issue? I have tried different methods from global.asx, wild card mapping and to no avail. I'm thinking this is window server 2003 R2 x64 specific issue.

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx

[Deploying Asp.Net MVC 2 /C# 4.0 application on IIS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319498/deploying-asp-net-mvc-2-c-4-0-application-on-iis-6)

Comment: What's the issue your having with the app? no compile? no routing correctly? other?

Comment: compile is fine, did a publish bin deploy on the server and got the HTTP 401.1 - Unauthorized: Logon Failed error

Comment: Try this step by step tutorial for Windows 2008 Server and IIS7. Might help you.

http://arturito.net/2011/01/21/publishing-asp-net-mvc2-application-on-windows-server-2008-iis-7-with-visual-studio-2008-on-platform-net-3-5-sp1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a Default.aspx on your home dir? If not, try adding one with this code-behind

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    public void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        // Change the current path so that the Routing handler can correctly interpret
        // the request, then restore the original path so that the OutputCache module
        // can correctly process the response (if caching is enabled).

        string originalPath = Request.Path;
        HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(Request.ApplicationPath, false);
        IHttpHandler httpHandler = new MvcHttpHandler();
        httpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext.Current);
        HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(originalPath, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried debugging it from application.Start() in Global.asax but it doesn't seem to hit it at all. I am thinking of permission related to configuration...

Comment: Maybe it isn't entering the ASP.NET pipeline. Does the Web Site have ASP.NET configured in IIS?
Also, try hitting default.aspx directly, or a Controller/Action route.

Comment: Checking if different version of asp.net needs to be registered. Didn't think of that one CGK

Comment: hmm now it gives An error occurred loading a configuration file: Access to the path 'c://mypath/web.config' is denied.

Comment: Looks like a permission problem...maybe IIS doesn't have permission to read that folder (i.e. is outside the default web path)

Comment: yeah that's what I'm thinking. I wish I am the full admin of this server box.

Comment: Do you have other web applications running on the server? Try copying the configuration.

Comment: No since this is a new server box.

Comment: @odez213 what was causing your problem, finally?